# I want only headings from that div

Tags: javascript

I want only headings from that `div`. I have many more other things it that `div`.

```js
let content = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

for (item in content){
    console.log(content[item].innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by headings? `<h1>`, `<h2>` tags?
You could change this to use a querySelector instead.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass h1')
```

This will return all the  elements inside the element with "myClass"

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll()` and loop through with `Array.forEach()`

```js
let content = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass > h1, .myClass > h2, .myClass > h3, .myClass > h4, .myClass > h5");

content.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el.innerText)
})
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <h1>Heading 1</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  <h2>Heading 2</h2>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```